# ssh-agent don't work,i cannot connect to my git server

Tags: ssh-agent

```
[suiyimen@localhost ~]$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_git
```

but return no such device or address

```
[suiyimen@localhost ~]$ ls -la ~/.ssh
```

it shows: id_rsa_git -> /tmp/ssh-DvbhW17778/agent.17778

I don't what do this mean.how can i solve the problem.I cannot git pull repo from my git server anymore.

Comment: "id_rsa_git -> /tmp/ssh-DvbhW17778/agent.17778" is a symbolic link to a temporary file, so I think maybe the keys needed to connect with your server is erased from tmp directory. Try to create again the key pair, and this time, try to be sure this time the place where is saved is not in a temporary directory

Comment: Thank for your answer!But it's little troublesome to create a new key pair,as it is a on a vpn, we use a id_rsa on the vpn to pull repo from the git server.It's not created by me ,i even don't know the git server address.Maybe I have to talk to my leader.

Comment: It seems related to the forwarding setting of my local machine.But I have remove all forwarding related ssh-agent settings.I don't know what to do?